# Building a data driven asp.net web forms application

Tags: asp.net, database, forms, web, data-driven

I need to create an asp.net web forms application which is data driven using VS. The application needs to have a login screen, with customers and staff, with a product page where they can select a product, then go to a shopping cart.

The staff need to be able to update and edit the products, and the orders must be processed in a table.

I'm finding this very confusing in what order etc... to do it in, could someone please just give me a basic guide if they dont mind to what order I should do this in with tips on how?

Any good resources will be greatly appreciated.

:) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start with the classic ["Contoso"](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Web-Forms-6c7197aa) sample as a starting point.